# Digital Clock Widget

Tags: clock, samsung-galaxy-s-4-mini

I use the Digital Clock Widget on my Samsung S4 Mini. Recently, I have noticed that when on 'Lock Screen' as small 'Qo' is displayed below the date:

[image: screenshot]
<sup>Screenshot (click to enlarge)</sup>

Anyone able to help identify this?